# sql refer row on masive insert using a stored procedures - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a table `task`, this table contains information of recurring tasks, fox example daily tasks, so **I repeat each task** because I want to know the result of each task over time

```
1/1/2014 Get Pizza OK 
1/2/2014 Get Pizza OK 
1/3/2014 Get Pizza Error 
1/4/2014 Get Pizza OK
```

For this I made a stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`db`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_repeat_task`()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Task
    (
     date_of_assignment,
     Some fields
    )    
    SELECT  
        DATE_ADD(tas.date_of_assignment, INTERVAL 1 DAY),
            another fields
    FROM Task tas       
    WHERE tas.date_of_assignment=CURRENT_DATE and many conditions
    )
    ;
END
```

This procedure is invoked every day 5 minutes before midnight. And produces something like this

[image: example]

**The problem is that I have to insert the id of the records added in another table**

For example

When I add 4 tasks in insert-select statement i need add these to another table

[image: example]

In my case, there can be multiple records for each task.

I can easily obtain `id_person` in my select, but not how to use it in the next insert.

I cant change the structure of the tables, I have only my stored procedure to work

I read about  `mysqli_insert_id`,  but not how to use it in my case

### EDIT

---

*based in b.b3rn4rd answer*

When i add the other field in cursor select

```
DECLARE records_to_clone_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT  `field1`, `field2`, `field3` FROM `Task` WHERE ... ;
```

In `FETCH` return more rows because as there is a one to many relationship in my tables

so the query returns with old fields

```
DECLARE records_to_clone_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT  `field1`, `field2` FROM `Task` WHERE ... ;
```

And i tried change the prepared statement for a classic Insert-Select

```
SET @NEW_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO Another_table
(
 id_task,
 id_person  
)    
SELECT tas.id_task,     
    pe.id_person
FROM Task tas       
INNER JOIN Person pe
    ON pe.id_person = tas.id_assigned
WHERE tas.id_task= @NEW_ID;

-- EXECUTE insert_responables USING @NEW_ID, @Var_3;
```

But does nothing, first prepared works well, and Select-Inser work in nornal query.

that I can do?

### EDIT 2

if I need to insert the values​​, but because they are different cause the cursor query returns more records and these are duplicated by the number of records in the field `is_person`

[image: example]